# Weak vs strong convergence for unitary operators

Tags: convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Suppose $H$ is a separable complex Hilbert space with inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ and norm $\|\cdot\|$, where $\|u\|^2 = (u,u)$. Suppose $u, u_1, u_2, \dots \in H$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = u$ strongly iff $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|u_n - u\| = 0$. $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = u$ weakly iff for all $v \in H$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} (u_n,v) = (u,v)$. Suppose $A, A_1, A_2 \dots$ are bounded operators on $H$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n = A$ strongly iff for all $u \in H$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n u = Au$ strongly. $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n = A$ weakly iff for all $u, v \in H$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} (A_nu,v) = (Au,v)$, i.e., $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n u = A_u$ weakly. (Note that convergence in the operator norm is a stronger notion that does not concern us here.) It is well known that weak operator convergence does not imply strong convergence, with the example given in the first answer below being standard. I had encountered a passage in which the author, having shown that $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n = A$ weakly, concludes that $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n = A$ strongly, giving by way of explanation the fact that---in the case at hand---$A, A_1, A_2, \dots$ are all unitary. This was not immediately obvious to me, but it is now; and I'll do penance by sketching the argument in case anyone is interested.

It is clearly enough to show this when $A$ is the identity operator; and for this it is enough to show that if $u, u_1, u_2, \dots$ are all unit vectors and $\lim_{n\to \infty} u_n = u$ weakly then $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = u$ strongly. To this end, suppose $\forall v \in H\,\,\lim_{n\to \infty} (u_n, v) = (u, v)$. Then, in particular, $\lim_{n\to \infty} (u_n, u) = (u, u) = 1$. Hence, $\lim_{n \to \infty} (u_n - u, u_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (u_n - u, u) = 0$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|u_n - u\|^2 = \lim_{n \to \infty} (u_n - u, u_n - u) = 0$. Hence, $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = u$ strongly.

Comment: "The question has been put on hold as off-topic." @RobertVanWesep: This may be because it is not so clear what $U_n$ are, and what weakly and strongly means here.

Comment: @user66081 The title fills in those details, I don't think that's why it was closed. There is a closure reason of "unclear what you're asking," but this was not cited here - the reason cited here was "off-topic."

Comment: @whacka: imho, the only missing item from [this list](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) is context, and the most missing item from [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) is definitions.

Comment: @user66081 From what I understand, the last item on that list is de facto one of the least contributory towards question closures. The OP didn't include any attempted work or thoughts or effort (or the next three things on that list), and this tends to rub voters the wrong way. Maybe my perception is off, and the five users can weigh in on their votes, but not providing definitions of terms which are standard in the relevant subject area does not seem to me to cause many closures, and in the instances where it is the cited reason is usually "unclear what you're asking" instead of "off-topic."